# Angular ag-grid Sequence for filter order from Alphabetical [Default] into Custom order

Tags: angular, filter, sequence, ag-grid, alphabetical

I am trying to have my own custom filter order sequence on ag-grid filter.

apart from default filter order [Alphabetical], I want to have own filtering sequence.

***As in the Ag-grid I'm able to display filter only in the alphabetical order,but in my case I want it as a custom filter-order for dynamic data.***

> For the reference I have included some data in the filter and observe
>   that is getting sorted in the alphabetical order.

**Please find the below plunker:**

[Plunker for filter Sequence](https://plnkr.co/edit/anwV9EkIfBEZ7tQoE8yO?p=preview)

Let me show below some sort of my UI

[image: Here, default order exists]

So, i am trying to change the custom filter order sequence.

For example

> - Critical
> - High
> - Medium
> - Low

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

My template :

**filter.component.ts**

```
 this.columnDefs = [
    {
          headerName: 'Severity',
          field: 'Severity',
          enableRowGroup: true,
          rowGroup: true,
    }
```

Comment: just apply a `sort` to it?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon can you please alter the code with sort.?

Comment: use `this.columnDefs.sort(.....);` and sort your array accordingly

Comment: @mast3rd3mon actually i'm sorting the filter data's not column datas...so how can i alter with that field: 'Severity'

Answer (score 0):

**hi, everybody thanks for your comments for this issue.**

Finally this issue resolved by my own research.

**please go-through below Plunker..,**

[Plunker for Custom  filter ordering sequence](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZzLURXGIDkGNtJ1wsEiq?p=preview)

> Every Ag-grid  filter data's display only in the alphabetical order.
>
> So, we want it as a custom filter-order for dynamic data.

**So,as per our implementation it is changed into custom manner shown as below..,**

**filter.component.ts**

```
 {
           headerName: 'Severity',
           field: 'Severity',
           filterParams: {
             values: getAllValues(),
             comparator: function (a, b) {
               const numA = parseInt(a);
               const numB = parseInt(b);
               if (numA > numB) {
                 return 1;
               } else if (numA < numB) {
                 return -1;
               } else {
                 return 0;
               }
             }
           },

function getAllValues() 
{ 
   const allPages: any = []; 
   allPages.push('Critical','High', 'Medium', 'Low'); 
   return allPages;
}
```